# AWS Linux - Installing packages (automatically install dependent packages)

Tags: linux, yum

I am trying to install Ted (RTF to PDF Convertor) on AWS Linux. Is there any command which will find and install all dependent packages?

I tried below command and referred a couple of posting on StackOverflow but none of those commands are working.

```
yum install -y http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/editors/ted/ted-2.23-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the below error.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: gtk2

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libpaper.so.1()(64bit)

Error: Package: ted-2.23-1.x86_64 (/ted-2.23-1.x86_64)
           Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

** Found 12 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
```

Comment: This is probably a better question for unix.stackexchange.com or a site for whatever OS it is you are installing this on since it is not programming related. Installing packages that are not configured specifically for the distro you are installing them on can be a giant pain in the rear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum will resolve dependencies automatically, but it can only download these dependencies from available repo's. It's hard to tell which distribution of Linux you're using(since you're using yum it's either Redhat or Centos).

most of the rpm dependencies are available in the base repo's so you just to enable those.

If you're using Centos 7, create a new file /etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Base.repo  and add the following content

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

save the file then clean yum cache by running:

```
yum clean all
```

Then try to download your rpm again

Comment: Thanks, It is rhel fedora using AWS Linux image. Should I be using EPEL as mentioned in  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: Here is info :
==========
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"